# Installing Pico TTS German Language on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, text-to-speech, raspberry-pi4, picotts

I'm trying to install a TTS module on my raspberry pi 4 with Python 3. I chose PicoTTS , but it doesn't really work. I'm using the following Code:

```
import wave
import io
from io import StringIO
import string
from picotts import PicoTTS

picotts.voice = 'de-DE'
wavs = picotts.synth_wav("Ich höre Dir zu")
wav = wave.open(StringIO.StringIO(wavs))
print(wav.getnchannels(), wav.getframerate(), wav.getnframes()
```

I installed *pip3 py-picotts* and *pip install ttspico*.
I get several Errors like:

1. NameError: name 'picotts' is not defined
2. AttributeError: type object 'io.stringIO' has no attribute 'StringIO' name 'picotts' is not defined
3. TypeError: Initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

I'm pretty new to python, so I don't know how to solve this. Is there anybody who can help? If you need any further information just let me know.
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to init PicoTTS `picotts = PicoTTS()`.
Your code should look like this:

```
import wave
import io
from io import StringIO
import string
from picotts import PicoTTS

picotts = PicoTTS() 
picotts.voice = 'de-DE' 
wavs = picotts.synth_wav('Hallo Welt!') 
wav = wave.open(StringIO.StringIO(wavs)) 
print(wav.getnchannels(), wav.getframerate(), wav.getnframes())
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue is `StringIO` is no longer used in Python 3, you need to use `BytesIO` instead. Combining with the fix given in the previous answer, your final working code should look like this:

```
import wave
from io import BytesIO
from picotts import PicoTTS

picotts = PicoTTS()
picotts.voice = 'de-DE' 
wavs = picotts.synth_wav('Hallo Welt!')
wav = wave.open(BytesIO(wavs))           
print(wav.getnchannels(), wav.getframerate(), wav.getnframes())
```